# d3.js - stop internl tick after alpha < 0.5 in force-directed graph

Tags: d3.js

I would like fore-directed graph stop the internal tick after alpha < .5. but below code doesn't work, the alpha value always 1.

```
forwardAlpha(force,.5,1000)
function forwardAlpha(force, alpha, max) {
  var i = 0;
  while(force.alpha() > alpha && i++ < max) {
   //console.log(force.alpha()) 
  }
  console.log(force.alpha()) 
  force.stop()
}
```

What's proper way to stop the internal tick after graph is stable?

```js
console.clear()

var data = {
  "nodes": [{
    "name": "Ben",
  },{
    "name": "May",
  }, {
    "name": "Jack",
  }, {
    "name": "Liam",
  },{
    "name": "Francis",
  }, {
    "name": "Owen",
  }, {
    "name": "Blake",
  }, {
    "name": "Julia",
  }],
  "edges": [{
    "source": "Ben",
    "target": "May"
  }, {
    "source": "Ben",
    "target": "Blake"
  }, {
    "source": "Ben",
    "target": "Owen"
  }, {
    "source": "Owen",
    "target": "Julia"
  }]
};

data.nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
  d.group = i
});

data.nodes.forEach(function(d) {
  data.edges.forEach(function(e) {
    if (e.source === d.name || e.target === d.name) {
      data.nodes.find(function(f) {
        return f.name === e.source
      }).group = d.group;
      data.nodes.find(function(f) {
        return f.name === e.target
      }).group = d.group;
    }
  })
})

var svg = d3.select("body").append('svg')
.style('border','5px solid red')

var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
  .data(data.edges)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .style("stroke", "#aaa")
  .style("stroke-width", 2);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 10)
  .style("stroke", "#444")
  .style("stroke-width", 2)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.group);
  })

var force = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink()
    .id(function(d) {
      return d.name
    }))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-5))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(15))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(150, 70))

force.nodes(data.nodes)
.force("link")
  .links(data.edges);

force.on("tick", ticked);

forwardAlpha(force,.5,1000)

function forwardAlpha(force, alpha, max) {
  var i = 0;
  while(force.alpha() > alpha && i++ < max) {
   //console.log(force.alpha()) 
  }
  console.log(force.alpha()) 
  force.stop()
}

function ticked() {
  edges.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })

  nodes.attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why not use `force.alphaMin(0.5);` which will stop the simulation when alpha falls below 0.5? Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @AndrewReid Great, that's exactly what I want. many thanks!